# The mysqli extension is missing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, linux-headers

Phpmyadmin Got an error "The mysqli extension is missing." but when try to install its go to :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysqli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-mysql' instead of 'php5.6-mysqli'
php5.6-mysql is already the newest version (5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Remove it and re-install again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work

Comment: :sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin And then :sudo apt install phpmyadmin
Already done, but still same error.

Comment: @George please help, its urgent. i will check every suggestion from AskUbuntu.

Comment: No remove the extension: `php5.6-mysqli`!

Comment: @George can you provide me comment ?

Comment: `sudo apt remove php5.6-mysql && sudo apt install php5.6-mysqli`

Comment: @George i got this.::sudo apt remove php5.6-mysqli && sudo apt install php5.6-mysqli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-mysql' instead of 'php5.6-mysqli'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-mysql' instead of 'php5.6-mysqli'
php5.6-mysql is already the newest version (5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918839/phpmyadmin-error-the-mysqli-extension-is-missing-after-upgrading-php-5-6-t

Comment: @George yes try now everyting ::sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin
sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apt-get purge php.*
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
But still error

Comment: Please add these steps to your question by editing it and add the results from the steps taken so we know how to help! Did you install phpmyadmin?

Comment: @George::::sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin
(Reading database ... 154098 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-1+deb.cihar.com~xenial.2) ...
dbconfig-common: dumping mysql database phpmyadmin to /var/tmp/phpmyadmin.phpmyadmin.2017-12-04-14.49.mysql.HtY5Mq.
dbconfig-common: dropping mysql database phpmyadmin.
dropping database phpmyadmin: success.
verifying database phpmyadmin was dropped: success.
dbconfig-common: revoking privileges for user phpmyadmin on phpmyadmin.
revoking access to database phpmyadmin from phpmyadmin@localhost: success.

Comment: @George::::sudo apt-get purge php5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php5.6*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 286 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 152422 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5.6 (5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Comment: @George sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions are included.

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

CAVEATS:

gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

Comment: @George::sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
All Done

Comment: @George now phpmyadmin is 403 forbidden

Comment: Look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/483297/why-do-i-always-get-a-403-error-with-phpmyadmin to solve that `403` error

Comment: @George   #mysql -V mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper #php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/mysql.so: file too short in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/mysqli.so: file too short in Unknown on line 0 /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,